# Vimrun.exe keeps opening and closing when statusline is updated

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, statusline, functions

I am working on a plugin and as part of that plugin I am trying to update the statusline with `setlocal statusline=%!GetMPCStatusline()`.

But this causes vimrun.exe to open and close very fast. This happens only when I focus in the window where the `statusline` is set and not the others.

I am attaching this screen grab of Vimrun.exe opening and closing. It just keeps happening in the background but it doesn't open anything.

[image]

So, Why is this happening and what can I do to make this stop?

PS: I am using GVim 7.4 on Windows.

Edit: I just tried this in the terminal Vim (powershell) and Vim in cygwin. There even though I am not getting this, something weird is happening there too. The cursor moves really really slow as if something is obstructing it.

Edit 2: This is the function its calling. It gets the output from the `mpc status`, `mpc playlist` command and parses them. When I run this function manually I can see the vimrun on the taskbar once and it disappears after that.

```
function! GetMPCStatusline()
    let cmd = "mpc status"
    let result = split(system(cmd), '\n')
    let status = len(result) == 3 ? result[2] : result[0]

    let [s:count, s:settings] =
                \ [len(split(system('mpc playlist'), '\n')),
                \ split(status, '   ')]

    let s:statusline = " "
                \ . s:settings[1] . " --- "
                \ . s:settings[2] . " ---%="
                \ . s:count . " songs "
    return s:statusline
endfunction
```

Edit 3: This doesn't happen when I have another function for the statusline. So, the only thing common in all the above tests is the statusline function above and hence I guess that has to be the reason why this is happening. Any ideas on why that is the case?

Comment: Sounds like an infinite while loop or nested recursion, but it's hard to say. I would start by making sure that your function `GetMPCStatusline()` doesn't have any problems.

Comment: Your function is called each time the screen is repainted for one reason or another (cursor move, edit, switch to another buffer, whatever). It takes time so you get that annoying delay and it happens very often so you get that flicker. You need to "debounce" it.

Comment: @romainl What does 'debounce' mean?

Comment: @Tumbler41 I've added the statusline function its calling. I don't see any problem with it but when I do run it manually I get that vimrun just once. So, since this function is getting called multiple times, I am guessing that's why vimrun keeps coming again and again.

Comment: "debounce" means that you must make sure the function is not called every couple of millisecond. Generally you do that by comparing the current timestamp with the timestamp of the last run. In other words, your function itself is not at fault, it's how you call it.

Comment: @romainl I remember reading sometime ago, about an option that reduces the frequency at which the statusline is drawn, but I couldn't find that now. Do you know how that can be changed? May be that will solve this issue.

Comment: My guess is, Vim needs a redraw after the system() call. Unfortunatly the redraw forces a re-evaluation of the statusline function, which causes again a redraw, which forces a re-evaluation of the statusline and so on...

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Is there anyway to break this cycle?

Comment: I don't know. Try using `:silent or :silent!`

Comment: How can `silent!` be used in the above case for the `system` call? It is inside the `split` function and I need the value returned from the shell.

Comment: `sil! let = ...` ?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop, Vim redraws the screen after the external command finished. According to the manual (`help !`), we can avoid "redrawing" use by `:silent !{cmd}` as @Christian Brabandt points out. Unfortunately, however, we can't avoid it on windows. This occurs only for gvim on windows (not occurred console vim on windows).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt `Silent` is sort of working in terminal vim but not in gvim.

Comment: @MS.Kim Yeah. Its still not working in gvim with the `silent` option.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop I am afraid, then there is no way around it.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to get this working. Thanks all of you for your help.